# Test button onClick function in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write my first app using react native framework. I have problem with test onClick function for button.

My App.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  refreshData() {
    console.log("download data from server placeholder");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <Button
          id="refreshButton"
          onPress={this.refreshData}
          title="Refresh"
          color="#000000"
          accesibilityLabel="Refresh AQI data"
          testID="refreshButton"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

My App.test.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

it('should render without throwing an error', function() {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  const refreshData = jest.fn();
  expect(wrapper.find('#refreshButton')).toHaveLength(1); // pass
  wrapper.find('#refreshButton').first().simulate('click');
  expect(refreshData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // fail
});
```

When I run npm test my test fail because refreshData has been called zero times. Looks like simulate function doesn't work, why? I tried call simulate without first() function but it didn't work. I'm not familiar with javascript, maybe I did an obvious mistake? I found that code in documentation and some tutorials which i found in internet. I'm writting simple ios application only for me and for training myself and I'm big fan of TDD. It is the reason that Unit Tests are important for me.

Comment: Does changing  to onPress={()=>this.refreshData()} make any difference?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I don't have problem with the onPress method because it works in simulator. I have problem only with tests.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure enzyme support ID and # selectors. Try adding a testID prop and calling it like this:

```
wrapper.dive().find("[testID='yourTestID']").simulate("press");
```

or

```
wrapper.dive().find("[testID='yourTestID']").onPress();
```

I am using both and they work fine.

Edit: now your problem is this

const refreshData = jest.fn();

Change to:

const refreshData = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "refreshData");

Edit2:

Update button code to this:

```
<Button
          id="refreshButton"
          onPress={this.refreshData}
          title="Refresh"
          color="#000000"
          accesibilityLabel="Refresh AQI data"
          testID="refreshButton"
        />
```

and test code to this:

```
it('should render without throwing an error', function() {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  let refreshData = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "refreshData");
  expect(wrapper.find('#refreshButton')).toHaveLength(1);
  wrapper.find("[testID='refreshButton']").onPress();
  expect(refreshData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

If that does not work, I am clueless.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I use simulate('press') I have the same fail, onPress() is not a function. Weird.

Comment: Change refreshData () to refreshData = () =>. It is a binding issue

Comment: It doesn't work. My code works, but test doesn't...
When I changed code to that you suggest I've got console.log works. I thing function has been called, but I have problem with asserion.

Comment: See my edited answer. You are declaring the spy wrong.

Comment: I modified my code and now I have this: https://pastebin.com/TeRXULbR I still have issue with test: "Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times." I see in console.log that my function is called but asertion doesn't work because looks like it something wrong with my mock function.

Comment: Instead of simulate use the second one. Just execute the onPress(). Also did you add the testID prop to the button right?

Comment: Yes, I don't have problem with calling function because I see "download data from server placeholder" in log. I have problem with assertion. Unfortunatelly onPress() doesn't work because I got error: onPress is not a function.

Comment: Simulate does not fail if the item is not found. Enzyme itself recommends using onPress.  If you get that error the problem is the selector. It is not finding the button in the snapshot or shallow component. How are you trying to execute the onPress on the test? Also how is your code now? Did you add the testID prop?

Comment: Hmm... I have testID selector like in code in the question. My test code is on pastebin. Durnig test execution I see Console.log with my tezy that i have defined in refreshData function. I think this is a prof that my function is executed. I’ll double check my code tomorow after work and paste everythin to pastebin.

Comment: This is my app and test code: https://pastebin.com/UK1rctCk In line 84 I see my console log from function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166645/discussion-between-sfratini-and-esio).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will now work because you haven't bind the function. Try to use arrow function instead like below so that you don't want to do that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  refreshData = () => {
    console.log("download data from server placeholder");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <Button
          id="refreshButton"`enter code here`
          onPress={this.refreshData}
          title="Refresh"
          color="#000000"
          accesibilityLabel="Refresh AQI data"
          testID="refreshButton"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the onPress={this.refreshData} part with below:

```
onClick={this.refreshData}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because react-native require onPress method.